# How to grep the last occurrence of a line pattern

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a file with contents

```
x
a
x
b
x
c
```

I want to grep the last occurrence,

```
x
c
```

when I try

```
sed -n  "/x/,/b/p" file
```

it lists all the lines, beginning `x` to `c`.

Comment: So you want to print from the last `x` up to the end?

Comment: as far as I know sed manipulates each line separately. ("The commands you give it are run on each line of input in turn" - quote from http://en.flossmanuals.net/command-line/sed/)

Answer (score 84):

I'm not sure if I got your question right, so here are some shots in the dark:

- Print last occurence of `x` (regex):

  ```
  grep x file | tail -1
  ```
- Alternatively:

  ```
  tac file | grep -m1 x
  ```
- Print file from first matching line to end:

  ```
  awk '/x/{flag = 1}; flag' file
  ```
- Print file from last matching line to end (prints all lines in case of no match):

  ```
  tac file | awk '!flag; /x/{flag = 1};' | tac
  ```

Comment: This `awk "/x/ { flag = 1 }; { if (flag == 1) print; }" txt` can be written some more simple like this `awk '/x/ {flag=1} flag' txt`

Comment: Using `tac` to facilitate getting the last instance is ingenious! Thank you

Comment: Need to be careful with the use of " or ' for the awk statement. I had trouble with the negation ! - I got an error "awk: cmd. line:1 ^backslash not last char - as I thought I had to use \!, but using ' prevents this.

Comment: Also the /x/ is a regular expression, you need to be aware of the chars used within the regular expression, need to escape. Luckily I could change the string in the file I had to search for which made the regular expression easier.

Comment: Note: `tac` requires the GNU utilities.

Comment: can someone explain what this command does? tac file | awk '!flag; /x/{flag = 1};' | tac

Comment: @HookUp `!flag` sets a condition on awk's default action (`print $0`). An unset `flag` is `false`. So this code prints lines as long as pattern `/x/` didn't set `flag=1`. But this solution isn't performing well. If (at all) one could probably better go `'1;/x/{exit}'` instead of `'!f;/x/{f=1}'`. But always given that you know for sure the file contains `/x/`.

Comment: @steffen - great - thank you for explaining and adding a better solution for this. I am not so familiar with linux commands so trying to understand how exactly this works : '1;/x/{exit}' ? does this mean as you as it finds the 1st occurrence of 'x' in the tac command result - it will exit and print the lines until the end of the file?

Answer (score 8):

```
grep -A 1 x file | tail -n 2
```

`-A 1` tells grep to print one line after a match line
with `tail` you get the last two lines.

or in a reversed way:

```
tac fail | grep -B 1 x -m1 | tac
```

Note: You should make sure your pattern is "strong" enough so it gets you the right lines. i.e. by enclosing it with `^` at the start and `$` at the end.

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'H;/x/h;$!d;x' file
```

Saves the last `x` and what follows in the hold space and prints it out at end-of-file.

Answer (score 1):

not sure how to do it using `sed`, but you can try `awk`

```
awk '{a=a"\n"$0; if ($0 == "x"){ a=$0}}  END{print a}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

**POSIX vi** (or ex or ed), in case it is useful to someone

Done in Command mode, of course

`:set wrapscan`

Go to the first line and just search Backwards!
`1G?pattern`

**Slower way**, *without* `:set wrapscan`

`G$?pattern`

Explanation:

`G` go to the last line

Move to the end of that line `$`

`?` search Backwards for `pattern`

The first *backwards* match will be the same as the last forward match

Either way, you may now delete all lines above current (match)

`:1,.-1d`

or

`kd1G`

You could also delete to the beginning of the matched line prior to the line deletions with `d0` in case there were multiple matches on the same line.

**POSIX awk**, as suggested at
[get last line from grep search on multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885554/get-last-line-from-grep-search-on-multiple-files)

`awk '(FNR==1)&&s{print s; s=""}/PATTERN/{s=$0}END{if(s) print s}'`

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna do awk in truly hideous one-liner fashion but getting awk to resemble closer to functional programming paradigm syntax without having to keep track when the last occurrence is

```
mawk/mawk2/gawk 'BEGIN { FS = "=7713[0-9]+="; RS = "^$";

 } END { print ar0[split($(0 * sub(/\n.+$/,"",$NF)), ar0, ORS)] }'
```

Here i'm employing multiple awk short-hands :

```
    sub(/[\n.+$/, "", $NF) # trimming all extra rows after pattern
```

`g/sub()` returns # of substitutions made, so multiplying that by 0 forces the `split()` to be splitting `$0`, the full file, instead.

`split()` returns # of items in the array (which is another way of saying the position of last element), so even though I've already trimmed out the trailing `\n`, i still can directly print `ar0[split()]`, knowing that **ORS** will fill in the missing trailing `\n`.

That's why this code looks like i'm trying to extract array items before the array itself is defined, but due to flow of logic needed, the array *will* become defined by the time it reaches **print**.

Now if you want something simpler, these 2 also work

```
mawk/gawk 'BEGIN { FS="=7713[0-9]+="; RS = "^$" 

   } END { $NF = substr($NF, 1, index($NF, ORS)); 
           
           FS = ORS; $0 = $0; print $(NF-1) }'
```

or

```
mawk/gawk '/=7713[0-9]+=/ { lst = $0 } END { print lst }'
```

- I didn't use the same `x|c` requirements as OP just to showcase these work regardless of whether you need fixed-strings or regex based matches.

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions only work for one single file, to print the last occurrence for **many files** (say with suffix `.txt`), use the following bash script

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for fn in `ls *.txt`
do
    result=`grep 'pattern' $fn | tail -n 1`
echo $result
done
```

where `'pattern'` is what you would like to grep.