# How to get last occurrence of a regexp match in a file to EOF

Tags: linux

c-shell, linux,

If I have file...

```
abc def xyz
123
abc ghi xyz
456
abc jkl xyz
789
```

I want the last match of /^abc.+xyz$/ to EOF...

```
abc jkl xyz
789
```

I saw this...
[How to grep the last occurrence of a line pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014194/how-to-grep-the-last-occurrence-of-a-line-pattern)

..and the 4th alternative of the first answer looks like what I want.  But I don't understand what "flag" means in the awk.  Used literally produces "flag: Event not found.".  I'm not even sure this will work in c-shell.

I'm hoping this will get posted.  It's a good thing to know how to do AND in my example, the pattern match is different.

Comment: Maybe the shell interprets the exclamation mark. Did you quote properly?

Comment: That was it.  Escaped with a \ and it worked.  Thanks !