# Finding a poorly named variable/object

Tags: javascript, python, search, grep

I am working with about 100 different files that are coded in python, JavaScript, and HTML. Many of these files are coupled in complicated ways. One of the problems I am having pretty consistently is trying to trace a variable or object back to where it is defined. My question is whether there is a smarter way to grep for a common word. For example, here are a few key-value pairs being returned at the end of a python function.

```
return {
     "form": context["form"],
     "groups": context["groups"],
     "facilities": context["facilities"],
     "student": user,
     "topics": topics
 }
```

If I grep for topics in the directories where these files are located:

```
$ grep 'topics' * -R
```

I end up with way too many files to sort through. I can't narrow down my search to just .py files, because some JS and HTML files are coupled too. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for the absolute first time the variable is declared in all files? Or just for each file, the first time a ____ variable is declared?

Comment: Well in terms of this file, I want to trace it back to where it was declared, and see what other files are using it. Basically I have a lot of variables (i.e topics, exercise_log, exerciseData) that are used in the majority of the files of this project. I want to be able to trace them back for the context of the file I am working in, but also in reference to the files that import it as well.

Comment: what file extensions are in the folder?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham you mean in the group of files I am working with? .py, .js, and .html

Comment: Have you tried using an IDE? Pretty much anything but IDLE, whether it's PyCharm or emacs tags-mode, is going to have some "find definition" routine full of complex regexps and heuristics far better than what you're going to hack up in a couple minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could search for `'topics = '` to narrow it down to only places where a variable named `topics` is assigned to. This makes it easier to find out where a global variable originated from.

Comment: what about 'topics= '?

Comment: Check for 'topics=' and 'topics= ' too as Padraic points out, or else you might miss something.

Comment: Probably you want the regexp `topics\s*=` (in Python syntax). `grep`, `ack`, and all other similar tools have regexp support.

Answer (score 0):

One smart way, as stated by Jack, is to use the `=` sign to narrow down your search. You can further narrow this down to assignment with the assumption that the first time it occurs, it's probably getting assigned. This can be done as such:

```
for f in $(find .); do grep -m 1 'topics[[:space:]]*=' -R; done
```

This will apply the `grep` command on each file in the current directory and all subdirectories. It will then take the first time that the string occurs (in this case, 'topics').

Here is the manual page for `grep` that shows all the options: [grep-man-page](http://ss64.com/bash/grep.html)

Here is the Stack Overflow question that shows how to `grep` on each file and get first/last result: [get-last-line-from-grep-on-multiple-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885554/get-last-line-from-grep-search-on-multiple-files)

Here is a Stack Overflow question dealing with whitespace in grep: [grep-regex-whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233159/grep-regex-whitespace-behavior)

Comment: "I can't narrow down my search to just .py files, because some JS and HTML files are coupled too"

Comment: Oh. I think I understand your question statement better now. I thought you meant you can't because you weren't sure how.

Comment: `topics.*=` is probably too general. Imagine `topics` is a list, and you do `topics[i] = new_topic` 30 times in the file…

Comment: Yeah, touche. I'll fix that.